# Do users need the same software needed to develop the program?

Tags: java

When I Make/Compile/Build a project, and then test it on someone else's computer, will all the items that I installed on my computer need to also be installed on the other persons computer as well? For example, I might be using GPU processing in my application, and for it to work on my computer I needed to download an Nvidia piece of software that was almost 1GB in size. The user that uses my application won't need to download that software will they? Here is the software that I needed to download: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

So will the end user need to have that installed as well? What if the end user doesn't have an Nvidia graphics card will the application still work?

Comment: OpenCL is an alternative you could look at.

Comment: Where can I find the OpenCL download? I can't find it.

Comment: If you want to target GPUs other than Nvidia ones, OpenCL is at `https://developer.nvidia.com/opencl` and `http://www.khronos.org/opencl/`

Comment: I have looked there, and I can't find any download links.

Comment: [**These answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190736/how-to-obtain-opencl-sdk) will help find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they need an Nvidia graphics card if you want to use cuda, as well as the software.

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022171/cuda-and-ati-graphic-card